# Map properties by nameing convention

Tags: automapper, automapper-6

I am using automapper to map some objects between the database and another representation.

The entity looks something like

```
public class MyEntity {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid RowId { get; set; }
}  

public class MyObject {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, the names and types are unaligned.
Since I got many Entities and Objects, I'd rather not `CreateMap<A, B>().ForMember(d => d.Id, mex => mex.MapFrom(s => s.RowId));`.

To not having to do the above Convention:

```
AddMemberConfiguration()
    .AddMember<NameSplitMember>()
    .AddName<ReplaceName>(_ => _.AddReplace("RowId", "Id"));
```

This does not what I suspected it to do and I was not able to figure out, how to use the ReplaceName Convention.
So I'd like to hear ideas about how to map that types.

`MyEntity` and `MyObject` both are base types, so I could also use that.

What I'm trying to archieve in pseudo-code:

```
if(source is MyEntity && target is MyObject)
{
     target.Id = source.RowId;
}
```

**ForAllMembers**
On recommendation of @lucian-bargaoanu I tried looking into `ForAllMembers`.
I did the following in the MapperProfile:

```
public class MapperProfile : Profile {
     public MapperProfile() {
         ForAllMaps(MapEntityBaseId);
     }

    protected void MapEntityBaseId(TypeMap map, IMappingExpression mex)
    {
        if (!map.SourceType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(EntityBase)))
            return;
        if (!map.DestinationType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(MyObject)))
            return;

        mex.ForMember("Id", opt => opt.MapFrom("RowId"));
    }
}
```

also the debugger hints me, that `ForAllMember` is executed as expected, it still fails the mapping.

I created a GIST for the ForAllMembers: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/511a1b69b795aa2bc7e7cd261fcb98b1

Comment: Try [Include](http://automapperdocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Mapping-inheritance.html).

Comment: Include will at least be less verbose than MapFrom, but still is a lot of plumbing

Comment: ForAllMaps would probably work too.

Comment: `ForAllMaps` looks very promising, and I can configure it properly, but it does "not work" - meaning, it will not map the property.

Comment: A repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail.

Comment: Your code works for me if I add the missing CreateMap.

Comment: I'll investigate further tomorrow, and provide a gist

Comment: I added a GIST, where I can Repro the "not-mapping"

Comment: That works for me. Upgrade.

Comment: I got AutoMapper 6.2.2 with Core 2.0 - I cannot upgrade.
At least the GIST was 6.2.2 with Core 2.0